# Nodejs puppeteer Output multiple parallel progress line in node js console

Tags: javascript, node.js, progress-bar, puppeteer, console.log

I created a simple program to upload files automatically on a website. I am using puppeteer for headless browsing login in and uploading. I am listening for changes to the upload bar by injecting mutation observer into the dom and log it into the console.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
var path = require('path');
var glob = require("glob");

async function upload(file_path, file_index) {
    // launch puppeteer
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    // some code here to navigate then upload to the website
    /*****************************************************

    UPLOADING CODE HERE...
    1. UPLOAD FILE
    2. THEN LOG THE PROGRESS TO CONSOLE
    there is some code here but i will not include it here to make it short

    ******************************************************/

    // everytime a change has been log in console
    await page.on('console', async (response) => {

        //fetch the progress percentage
        var percent = await page.$eval('#progressbar', el => el.innerText);

        // log the progress
        console.log('File ' + file_index + ' Percent uploaded: ' + percent)

    });

}

// lets say there are 5 files in the server
glob("files/*.mp4", function(er, files) {

    files.forEach(function(file, video_index) {
        upload(file, video_index);
    });

});
```

Uploading is working perfectly but the problem is when outputting the progress into the console. My program keeps on writing newline and not creating parallel progress lines. Lets say i will upload 5 files asynchronously. What the program is outputting is this:

[image]

what i want to see is this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution but i don't think this is the ideal approach. Feel free to share your ideas. I will store the data into an array then output the array for every mutation changes. Or store it in a buffer.

Edit. I found a solution on github.

https://github.com/ivanseidel/node-draftlog